# Selenium loads profile only in the deprecated way (Python)

Tags: python, selenium, firefox, selenium-firefoxdriver, firefox-profile

I tried the recommended method of loading a profile, but it's not working for me. It simply opens an empty profile.

```
from selenium.webdriver import Firefox
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.options import Options


profile_path = r'E:/Python/seleniumProfile'
options=Options()
options.set_preference('profile', profile_path)
driver = Firefox(options=options)
driver.get("https://www.google.com")
```

No warning or error message is given, even if I type an invalid folder as the profile_path.

Old way works great, but gives the deprecation warning:

```
fp = webdriver.FirefoxProfile('E:/Python/seleniumProfile')
driver = webdriver.Firefox(fp)
driver.get("https://www.google.com")
```

> DeprecationWarning: firefox_profile has been deprecated, please use an Options object

I guess I can live with the warnings, but any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

This error message...

```
firefox_profile has been deprecated, please pass in an Options object
```

...implies that usage of *`FirefoxProfile()`* have been *Deprecated* and with [selenium4](/questions/tagged/selenium4) and to use a *custom profile* you have to use an instance of `Options` . This *DeprecationWarning* was inline with the following *CHANGELOGS*:

- [*Selenium 4 beta 1*](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/d7ae19b04be2fca96e577c8c34184d03ad0dda8a/py/CHANGES#L118)

  - *Deprecate all but `Options` and `Service` arguments in driver instantiation. (#9125,#9128)*
- [*Selenium 4 beta 2*](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/d7ae19b04be2fca96e577c8c34184d03ad0dda8a/py/CHANGES#L104)

  - *Deprecate using a Firefox profile in Options*
- [*Selenium 4 Beta 3*](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/d7ae19b04be2fca96e577c8c34184d03ad0dda8a/py/CHANGES#L84)

  - *Only give deprecation warning if Profile is being used in options*

---

### Solution

To use an existing *firefox profile* you can use the following solution:

```
from selenium.webdriver import Firefox
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.options import Options

profile_path = r'C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Roaming\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles\s8543x41.default-release'
options=Options()
options.set_preference('profile', profile_path)
service = Service('C:\\BrowserDrivers\\geckodriver.exe')
driver = Firefox(service=service, options=options)
driver.get("https://www.google.com")
```

---

### tl; dr

[Setting a custom profile](https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/webdriver/capabilities/firefox/#setting-a-custom-profile)

Comment: Didn't work for me. I thought maybe there could be a typo in my code, but I can't find it. Thanks anyway.

Comment: `options.set_preference("profile", profile_path)` doesn't set profile for me. Only calling `options.add_argument("-profile")` and `options.add_argument(profile_path)` does.